# After I hit enter in Vim, my indentation is off

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim and I want to go to a new line I hit `o` and the indentation is a bit off by `8` spaces. The weird thing is it only happens to just some files not all of them. Not sure if there's a way to self-diagnose?

Here's an example

`config.js` file

```
redis: {$ // < hit `o` from here and
         $ // << my cursor would be here
}
```

Here's my vimrc

```
set number
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set nowb
set smartindent
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
```

Comment: Settings can be overridden depending on the filetype. What does `:set ft?` say? Is it recognized as a javascript file? If so, look for a file named "javascript.vim" in $HOME/.vim/indent or some subdirectory of /usr/share/vim, if you use Linux or Mac OS.

Comment: It says filetype=javascript

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your example and `filetype=javascript`...

Comment: It doesn't happen to me all the files as well. Which why it baffles me.

Comment: You can try following the steps in [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) to see if you can narrow it down to a specific plugin or setting...

Comment: is there any change after enabling `cindent` and removing `smartindent`?